# How to get an isomorphic ideal from a given one?

Tags: ring-theory, lie-algebras, ideals, algebras

It's an open question, in general given an ideal in rings, algebras, lie algebras, etc., do you know how to get another one isomorphic to the given one?

If you want to know the context: I have $I\unlhd J\unlhd L$, I'm looking for an ideal isomorphic to I (as lie algebra).

Comment: Isomorphic as....? Modules? Algebras?

Comment: as Lie algebras, but if you know some way as another structure the idea could help me

Comment: Yeah... no clue.